# BERT zero layer fixed word embeddings

Tags: pytorch, word-embedding, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to do an experiment with bert zero-layer vectors (input vectors), which I understand are of dimension 128.

I can not find **where I can get a file with the tokens and their vectors.**
Is there such a thing?
Is there a file in the Glove/word2vec format but of BERT's input vectors?

I'd appreciate any help with this!!
Thanks,

Comment: I believe it is! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: No problem, please mark your question as duplicate.